# Check is qr_code_scanner scanned a barcode or qr code

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to check if the code scanned using the qr_code_scanner plugin was a bar or qr code something like

```
if(code.isbarcode){
do something
}
```

Basically I have a scanner that can scan for two different cases. One case involves scanning a barcode which the result is passed in an endpoint and another case involves scanning a qr code which the result will be passed in a different endpoint.